# Не запускается активность из фрагмента

Tags: java, android

Мой фрагмент вызывается из класса: public abstract class DrawerActivity extends CapsuleActivity , из enum DrawerItem . Хотелось бы, чтобы при вызове фрагмента, он сразу запускал активность, но не получается.
Вот фрагмент:

```
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import monogramm.parallel.activities.Gamma;

public class GammasFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void startActivity(Intent intent){
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Gamma.class);
        getActivity().startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что и где не так ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну а вы и не запускаете активити. Вы просто переопределили зачем-то метод `startActivity()`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Вот примерно так открывается новая активити. А еще есть [документация](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#java), там более подробно можно почитать.

Comment: Спасибо, полезная информация.

Comment: Все хорошо, все работает, но... дополнительный   .xml   и дополнительная кнопка.   А как без них ???

Comment: В смысле доп XML и доп кнопка? Ну вызовите этот метод не на кнопку, а там где вам нужно